# How to stream video using C/C++

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, libvlc

I want to stream video to a file/ or memory buffer using VC++ on windows. 
Can anyone suggest easy to integrate library?(that has one H,one LIB and one DLL).

I am exploring the libVLC right now and gonna explore FFMPEG also.
dont want to spend time in building these complex software fully myself, would appreciate any help/pointer/ references.

---

My ultimate goal is to stream a video and consume the stream on HTML5 viewer.
I tried streaming using VLC media player and streamed to a OGG file, I used same OGG file in a HTML5-Video tag and it worked.

Now I want to do the streaming part  using libVLC instead of VLC media player.
I want to stream the video file to File or memory stream.

I have found this sample  https://wiki.videolan.org/Stream_to_memory_(smem)_tutorial/

BUt unsure of how to get started ?
1) Where do i get the libVLC.dll, libVLC.lib, libVLC.h , Is there any sample visual studio that has everything setup and I can straight begin to write the code using libVLC etc.

2) Since libVLC is said to depdend on 200+ other libraries/modules/plugins, what will I have include and  distribute with my application ?
http://www.enjoythearchitecture.com/vlc-architecture.html
https://wiki.videolan.org/Contrib_Status/

3) streaming format  : above example seems to stream into PCM format, cant I get it stream in some format that has better codec and regonized by HTML5 ?  For example when i tried using VLC media player , my options were as following 
   :sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=C:\Users\testUser\stream-output.ogg,no-overwrite} :sout-keep

Answer (score 3):

Finally  I was able to get through VLC.

You need to download correct set of files

download 7z package from http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html

and thats all you need.

It has DLLs, LIBs, and Headers.
thats all you need to get started.

Any sample program of VLC would require these three.
If anybody need any  help, please feel free to buzz me.

Comment: Hy sir ! Actually I am also trying to do the video streraming through libVlc but not getting how to do it. Can you please help. You can find more about my problem in this stack overflow question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65159652/how-to-stream-the-video-using-vlc-qt-wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Yes Arif, You are right. But One more thing you also need some plugins, they are also equally important. Plugins are also there(7z package), but until you will not put these plugins near exe file or set VLC_PLUGIN_PATH in environment variable, the application will not work.

Comment: Thanks Mohit, Yeah I had got all plugins from 7z package and added the plugins path while initializing lvc and it all worked fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have posted another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042025/whats-the-difference-between-stream-generated-by-ffmpeg-vs-lib-vlc). Do you have any clue on that ?