# Whats the difference between stream generated by ffmpeg vs lib VLC

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, libvlc

I am trying to stream a Mp4 file to a webm file.

After that I am reading this file chunk by chunk and feeding it to HTML5 viewer
(video tag of html 5 viewer)

in order to stream from MP4 file webm file I have had three options

1) Stream out using VLC media player application
2) Stream using libVLC through C code
  [How to stream video using C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002874/how-to-stream-video-using-c-c)
3) stream using ffmpeg commandline 
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c:v libvpx -c:a libvorbis -pix_fmt yuv420p -quality good output.webm

While comsuming this webm generataed by all three options. 1st and 2nd is not working. While 3rd one is working.  1st and 2nd works only after streaming to file is completed and when last chunk of output file is fed to html5 video player.

It seems vlcplayer and libVLC is not generating the required fragments with keyframes that are generated by ffmpeg.

Is there anyway we can instruct libVLC or VLCplayer also to generated fragments with keydrame info ?