# How to stream the video using VLC-QT wrapper

Tags: qt, qt5, vlc, libvlc, vlc-qt

I want to stream the video using `RTSP, HTTP and UDP`  as they are supported by `vlc`. I am using `Qt5` and as `Qt` don't have that much good media libraries so I go for open source and now using `libvlc` through `VLC-Qt` wrapper.

I am able to receive the stream videos in my program, The source code for receiving the streaming video is given below

```
void player::on_actionNETWORK_STREAM_triggered()
{
    QString url= QInputDialog::getText(this,tr("Open Url"),tr("Enter the URL you want to play"));

    if(url.isEmpty())
        return;
    else
    {
        m_media=new VlcMedia(url,m_instance);
        playlist.append(url);
        m_mediaList->addMedia(m_media);
        m_player->open(m_media);
    }
}
```

To receive the streaming video I just put the url of that video into the new `VlcMedia` instance but don't know how to stream a video.

While reading the documentation of the `VLC-QT` wrapper I read that it have one `class` named `VlcVideoStream`  but I am not getting how to use that class to do the streaming. The link of the documentation of this `class` is given below

https://vlc-qt.tano.si/reference/1.1/classvlcvideostream

EDIT 1

I searched on the internet more about this thing then I found some discussion of how to use `VlcVideoStream` and I have implemented the code for that. The source code is given below

```
class VideoStreaming : public VlcVideoStream
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit VideoStreaming(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void frameUpdated();
};
```

```
void VideoStreaming::frameUpdated()
{
    int rows,cols;
    
    std::shared_ptr<const VlcAbstractVideoFrame>  frame=  renderFrame();
    
    if (!frame)
        return; // LCOV_EXCL_LINE

    
    rows = frame->height + frame->height/2;
    cols = frame->width;
    
    qDebug()<<"Frame updated gets called";
}
```

and instantiate it with the following line

```
    m_video_stream= new VideoStreaming(ui->m_video);
    m_video_stream->init(m_player);
```

Now I am able to receive the `YUV` frames of the video but don't know how to stream the video till now. Any help is appreciated. Even I am open to the pure  `libvlc` streaming solution as `VLC-QT` wrapper is not that much good wrapper to support video streaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use the `setOption()` function of `VlcMedia` to set the streaming attributes and it works.

```
    m_media = new VlcMedia("file:///home/vinay/Media Library/lion-sample.webm",m_instance);
    m_media->setOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:udp{dst=127.0.0.1:1234}");
    m_media->setOption(":no-sout-all");
    m_media->setOption(":sout-keep");
```

Those string arguments are taken from the `vlc` application. When we stream the video through `vlc` application, In the last window it show all of these parameters which you set. So i just copy those parameters and passed it as an argument to the `setOption()` and It works.

You can read my detailed discussion of this topic in this link

https://forum.qt.io/topic/121483/how-to-stream-the-video-using-vlc-qt-wrapper-or-libvlc/10